# where is transaction confirmation number in bitcoin source?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions

I have try to check in bitcoin source code.

i want to see confirmation number code but i have not found.

where is transaction transaction confirmation number in bitcoin source ? how to update it ?

Thanks you

Comment: What do you need that isn't found by downloading, unzipping and then using `findstr /s confirmation *.cpp *.h`?

Comment: i did not see as your guidance. normally when we transfer bitcoin we need to till 6 confirmations ? where it is in source code ? can we reduce to 3 confirmations ?